# Cordova platform add IOS Cocoapods and phonegap-push-plugin error in CMD

Tags: ios, cordova, visual-studio-2015, phonegap-plugins

I'm working on a Cordova app in Visual Studio 2015.
I tried to add the iOS platform to cordova by running this in cmd

> *C:\cordovaProjectDirectory > cordova platform add iOS*

this is the error I get
[cocoapods error.jpg](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3u7PH.jpg)

I have been trying to get push notifications to work on my iOS device via remote build and I suspect this might be causing the problem.

Android device is working fine

What I have tried :

> - removing and installing phonegap-push-plugin
> - removing and installing ios platform
> - deleting platform/ios folder and clearing cordova cache
> - create empty project and run same cmds

Some info :

> - cordova cli  6.3.1
> - phonegap-push-plugin 1.9.2
> - node 5.6.0
> - npm 3.6.0

Alot of the solutions I see for installing Cocoapods are for MAC Terminal. 
I have no idea what I'm missing or doing wrong.

Any advice is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Try installing cocoapods via "sudo gem install cocoapods" on your mac. See: https://guides.cocoapods.org/using/getting-started.html

Comment: Thanks for the tip! I've done that as well.
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/cocoapods-1.1.1/lib/cocoapods.rb